# How to make a recursive function to generate the combination of numbers eg. for n=3, (1,1,1),(1,1,2) and so on?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def generate(n):
    t=[]
    lol=[[] for i in range(n**n)]
    helper(n,t,lol)
    return(lol)

def helper(n,t,lol):
    global j

    if len(t)==n:
        lol[j]=lol[j]+t 
        j += 1
        return
    
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print(i)
        t.append(i)
        helper(n,t,lol)
        t.pop()

j=0

print(generate(2))
print(generate(3))
```

Here, for n=2, i'm getting expected answer.
But for, n=3, it is showing Index Error:

```
in helper
    lol[j]=lol[j]+t 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You did not reset `j` to `0` before calling `generate` for the second time. It is not a good method to use global variable here.

Comment: I am usually not that bad at those so called "IQ test" "what is the next element in sequence" (even tho they are all disputable, since there are usually more than one possible logic). But here, I must confess that I fail from your two triplet to understand what "and so on" means. `(1,1,3), (1,1,4), (1,1,5), (1,1,6), ..., (1,1.1000000000), (1,1,1000000001), (1,1,1000000002), ...`? The word "combination" doesn't help, since it forbids `(1,1,1)` and `(1,1,2)`. So, obviously you're not thinking really of combinations. Can you help us guess what you have in mind?

Comment: When `helper` is called *the-first-time* what do you need `j` to be? The *second-time*? The *third-time*? Why isn't `j` a parameter of `helper`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```py
def generate(n):
    def helper(m, n, s):
        if m==0:
            print(s)
        else:
            for x in range(1,n+1):
                helper(m-1, n, s+[x])
    assert n>=1
    helper(n, n, [])
```

Examples:

```
>>> generate(1)
[1]
>>> generate(2)
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
>>> generate(3)
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 2]
[1, 3, 3]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 3]
[3, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 2]
[3, 2, 3]
[3, 3, 1]
[3, 3, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
>>>
```